# pass argument to filter function in PHP

Tags: php, function

at one point in my function I need to filter an array  based on a last digit of a key, but I cannot pass argument to the function I'm using to filter

here's the code:

```
    function functionName($number){
        //some code
        $items = array_filter(SomeClass::$items, function ($item, $number){
            return ($item%10 == $number);
        }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
        //some code
    }
```

what can I do to make sure the inner function uses **$number** passed to functionName()?

Comment: @Carcigenicate edited, maybe OP was thinking about closures

Comment: function ($item, $number) use ($yourvar) {...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables to closure function by "use"
Eg.

```
function ($var) use ($yourVarThatYouWannaPass) { return $var;}
```